# Does MVVM design pattern using Bridge design pattern?

Tags: bridge

After reading about *bridge* design pattern I inspect other design patterns and find out: patterns which using aggregation of abstract class / interface in some way using [Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern).
Does it?

Comment: it depends on the impementatioin of a certain mvvm framework, it is not a pre-requisite for the pattern per-se

Comment: for example in my own [mvvm framework](https://github.com/foo123/modelview.js) i dont use it

Comment: also beware of frameworks which over-design or over-engineer with design patterns (sometimes by ignorance)